# What is the word that means "creating complexity"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word I'm looking for was used in the context of describing some versions of Cellular Automata (i.e. Conway's Game of Life). It means creating complex, interesting results. I would liken the word to "generative". Does anyone know what word I'm looking for?

Comment: Complexitificating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, it can be describe as

**Synthesis**:
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synthesis

> **1.c** the combining of often diverse conceptions into a coherent whole; also : **the complex so formed.**
>
> > "In addition, there is growing recognition of abiotic organic synthesis in various geological materials."

Answer (score -1):

I believe I have just remembered the word. It was **emergent**.

Comment: You might explain how 'emergent properties' of a group go beyond what an individual can do.